# Análise de Complexidade de Algoritmo

Tags: c, algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Um professor da minha faculdade passou um exercício para analisar a complexidade temporal desse algoritmo, mas eu não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum. Alguém sabe me dar uma luz de como separar o algoritmo?

```
 int Algoritmo(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0, i=1, j=0;
    int h;
    while (i<n && k+j+1<n ) {
        if (A[k+j] == A[(i+j)%n]) {
            j = j+1;
        }
        else if (A[k+j] < A[(i+j)%n]) {
            i = i+j+1;
            j = 0;
        }
        else if (A[k+j] > A[(i+j)%n]) {
            h = max(i, k+j+1);
            k = h;
            i = h+1;
            j = 0;
        } 
    }
    return k;   
}
```

Tipo, quando é com uma variável no `while`, fica bem fácil,
Mas nesse caso, o `i`, `j` e `k` vão mudar de formas diferentes de acordo com cada `else`...

O que eu queria saber é, existe algum meio de descobrir essa complexidade de modo fácil ou eu teria que ficar testando e achar a hora em que o algoritmo começa a repetir?

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro, dá para eliminar o `h` do algoritmo para simplificar um pouco mais:

```
int Algoritmo(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0, i=1, j=0;
    while (i<n && k+j+1<n ) {
        if (A[k+j] == A[(i+j)%n]) {
            j = j+1;
        }
        else if (A[k+j] < A[(i+j)%n]) {
            i = i+j+1;
            j = 0;
        }
        else if (A[k+j] > A[(i+j)%n]) {
            k = max(i, k+j+1);
            i = k+1;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

`n` me parece ser o tamanho do array. Pois o array é acessado nas seguintes posições:

- `(i+j)%n` o que vai dar alguma posição entre `0` e `n-1`.
- `k+j`, mas a condição do `while` garante que `k+j+1<n` e isso também significa que `k+j<n` e portanto é alguma coisa entre `0` e `n-2`.

Dentro do `while` há três condições, comparando o `A[k+j]` com o `A[(i+j)%n]`. Ou estes dois elementos são iguais, ou o primeiro é maior, ou o segundo elemento é maior. Logo, sempre haverá uma e apenas uma das condições sendo verdadeira em cada iteração do `while`.

Vamos ver como `j` evolui ao longo do tempo:

```
j=0;     // Inicial
j = j+1; // Primeira situação (==)
j = 0;   // Segunda situação (<)
j = 0;   // Terceira situação (>)
```

Ou seja, `j` começa em zero, vai incrementando de um em um de vez em quando ou então volta para zero. Para simplificar a análise, vamos por ora assumir que a primeira condição (do `==`) nunca será verdadeira e que portanto `j` seria sempre zero. Sabemos que isso não é correto, mas faremos apenas para entender melhor o que se passa no algoritmo. Desta forma, ele ficaria assim:

```
int AlgoritmoErrado(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0, i=1;
    while (i<n && k+1<n) {
        if (A[k] < A[i%n]) {
            i = i+1;
        }
        else if (A[k] > A[i%n]) {
            k = max(i, k+1);
            i = k+1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Uma vez que pela definição do `while`, temos que `i<n`, podemos eliminar o `%n`:

```
int AlgoritmoErrado(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0, i=1;
    while (i<n && k+1<n) {
        if (A[k] < A[i]) {
            i = i+1;
        }
        else if (A[k] > A[i]) {
            k = max(i, k+1);
            i = k+1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Vejamos o que este algoritmo faz. Sabemos que ele funciona apenas quando todas as posições do array têm valores diferentes (afinal, eliminamos o caso do `==` que precisaria do `j` para funcionar).

Começamos com `k=0` e `i=1`. Os elementos `A[0]` e `A[1]` são comparados, se o `A[0]` for menor que o `A[1]`, o `i` será incrementado, e então vamos comparar o `A[0]` com o `A[2]` e se a condição se manter, vamos comparar o `A[0]` com o `A[3]`. Ou seja, a condição do `<` se mantém quando o elemento `A[k]` é menor do que os elementos que o sucedem. Se tivermos o caso aonde o primeiro elemento do array for o menor de todos, zero será retornado pelo algoritmo, o que parece indicar que ele descobre aonde está o elemento de menor valor.

Vamos ver o que ocorre se cairmos na condição `>`. Começamos comparando `A[0]` com `A[1]` e o menor elemento é o `A[1]`. Então comparamos `A[1]` com `A[2]`, depois `A[2]` com `A[3]`, e o valor do `k` é sempre o valor do índice do array com o menor elemento.

**Concluímos que este algoritmo retorna a posição no array que tem o menor valor encontrado.**

Sabendo deste comportamento, temos que neste caso aonde não há `j`, o `k` sempre será menor (e nunca igual) ao `i`. Portanto podemos simplificar o algoritmo para o seguinte:

```
int AlgoritmoErrado(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0, i=1;
    while (i<n && k+1<n) {
        if (A[k] < A[i]) {
            i = i+1;
        }
        else if (A[k] > A[i]) {
            k = i;
            i = k+1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Que é equivalente a isso:

```
int AlgoritmoErrado(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0, i=1;
    while (i<n && k+1<n) {
        if (A[k] > A[i]) {
            k = i;
        }
        i = i+1;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Uma vez que temos sempre que `k<i`, então a condição `k+1<n` é redundante, pois só será verdadeira se `i<n` também for. Então o algoritmo fica assim:

```
int AlgoritmoErrado(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0, i=1;
    while (i<n) {
        if (A[k] > A[i]) {
            k = i;
        }
        i = i+1;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Que por sua vez é equivalente a isso:

```
int AlgoritmoErrado(int A[], int n) {
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
        if (A[k] > A[i]) k = i;
    }
    return k;
}
```

E neste ponto já está óbvio que ele vai iterar exatamente **n-1** vezes, o que seria **Θ(n-1)**, mas como o **n** domina sobre o **1** temos **Θ(n)**.

E quanto ao `j`? Será que o `j` destroi o **Θ(n)** que o algoritmo seria?

Os elementos são acessados nas posições `k+j` e `(i+j)%n`. Na primeira condição, o `k+j` cresce, aproximando o fim do algoritmo um passo na direção da condição `k+j+1<n`. Na terceira condição, o `k` aumenta e o `j` volta a zero, mas o valor de `k+j` também aumenta porque `k = max(i, k+j+1)`, o que garante que o novo valor de `k+j` será maior ou igual ao `k+j+1` anterior. O `k+j` só pode diminuir na segunda condição, mas essa redução só vai ocorrer após uma sequência de entradas na primeira condição, o que fará o `i` aumentar em lugar pulando por cima de todas as posições `k+j` e aproximando o fim do algoritmo da condição `i<n` enquanto que o `k+j` só retrocede até o ponto antes da entrada na condição do `==` pela primeira vez.

Assim conclui-se que a cada iteração ou chega-se um passo mais perto da condição de parada `k+j+1`, ou então retrocede-se alguns passos desta condição, mas avança-se este mesmo número de passos mais um em direção a condição de parada `i<n`.

Se **a** for o número de passos realizados na primeira e na terceira situação se aproximando de se atingir a condição de parada do `k+j+1` e **b** for o número de passos realizados na segunda situação se aproximando para atingir a condição de parada do `i<n`, então em no máximo **a+b** passos, pelo menos uma das condições será atingida. Dado que sabemos que **a<=n** e **b<=n** então **a+b<=2n**.

Isso significa que garantidamente, em não mais que **2n** iterações o algoritmo termina e em não menos que **n-1** iterações ele termina. Assim o algoritmo é **Ω(n-1)** e **O(2n)**. Como os fatores constantes não importam e o **n** domina sobre o **1**, então **Ω(n-1)** é o mesmo que **Ω(n)** e **O(2n)** é o mesmo que **O(n)**. E se o algoritmo é **Ω(n)** e **O(n)** ao mesmo tempo, então ele é **Θ(n)**.